# Prop Suggestions/IntelliSense for own vue components

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I'm cleaning up my vue.js code and I'm about to create some of my own specific components. I'm using vetur as an extension for VS Code. I read that it's possible to provided auto-complition and descriptions for my component tags and attributes.

[The Vetur Docs](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/component-data.html#supported-frameworks) say I have to create tags.json and attributes.json files and add them to my package.json. After restarting VS Code it should work. But it doesn't. Has anyone managed to achive this and sees where I'm making a mistake?
Thanks in advance!!

This is the content of my tags.json

```
{
    "mex-btn": {
        "description": "My Mex Button",
        "attributes": "["content"]
    }
}
```

This is the content of my attributes.json

```
{
    "mex-btn/content": { "description": "Content of the Button"}
}
```

and this is the vetur key in my package.json

```
   "vetur": {
    "tags": "./tags.json",
    "attributes": "./attributes.json"
  }
```

Comment: do you use html in your templates? Or pug?

Comment: there's also a typo in tags.json: remove the quotation mark before the array definition for the `attributes` property